# Refreshing OIDC token automatically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

In our project we need to consume a TokenMaster service which passes us a token for a valid request and also the token is valid for exact on hour from the time of response and expiry time is also included in the response received. The token provided is a JWT token.
I have two approached here:-

a.) To use a static field and store a Pair<String-Token, ExpiryTime>, while sending a request we'll check if the token has expired or not and based on that we will take make a call for a new token or use and existing one.

b.) use an existing library that can do this for us i.e. refreshed token automatically.

My question is do we have a library that can do this(refreshing token) automatically for us. Our application is a spring boot application developed in Kotlin.